# sending Unicode chars with AJAX in IE 8

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, xmlhttprequest

I have IE 7 + 8 and page which has

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
```

I'm sending string using AJAX which has Arabic character.

my problem is that the string which arrives to the server has ???? values on IE 7 and Gibrish on IE8. English chars are just fine.

```
function getXmlHttpObject()
{
    try
    {  
        // Firefox, Opera 8.0+, Safari  
        xmlHttp=new XMLHttpRequest();  
    }
    catch (e)
    { 
        // Internet Explorer  
        try
        {    
            xmlHttp = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");   
        }
        catch (e)
        {    
            try
            {      
                xmlHttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");      
            }
            catch (e)
            {      
                alert("Your browser does not support AJAX!");      
                return false;     
            }    
        }  
    }   
    return xmlHttp;
}
```

and then the AJAX itself:

```
          function updateName()
            {
                //updateLocal();
                xmlHttp = getXmlHttpObject();

                var username = document.getElementById('username').value;
                xmlHttp.onreadystatechange=function(){onResponseUpdateOrderName();};
                var params = "username=" +username;
                xmlHttp.open("POST",myRootLink+"/myServlet/?"+params,true);
                var boundaryString = 'bound';
                var boundary = '--' + boundaryString;
                var requestBody = [
                boundary,
                params,
                boundary,
                ].join('\r\n');
                xmlHttp.setRequestHeader("Content-length", requestBody.length);
                xmlHttp.setRequestHeader("Connection", "close");
                 xmlHttp.setRequestHeader('Content-type', 'text/xml;charset=utf-8');
                xmlHttp.send(requestBody);
            }
```

How can I send it solve this issue?

Comment: If the user is not entering data as UTF-8 (such as pasting from MS Word), then it will certainly be garbled when sent via AJAX, which only handles UTF-8. Garbage in = garbage out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace

```
var params = "username=" +username;"
```

with

```
var params = "username=" +username;
```

Comment: soory but these line are the same. what should I replace it with? :)

Comment: @danny.lesnik: You've got an unterminated double-quote (`"`) in the first line.

Comment: Thanks I just removed some parmaters while posting this code, but it has nothing to do with my original problem.

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
          xmlHttp.setRequestHeader('Content-Type','application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8');
```

It work for me.